# Does "I do not own myself" sound right?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Basically, I just read something in Spanish saying that; since they belong to God they do not own themselves.

So, would saying:

> I do not own myself.

... be correct? Or, is there a better way to say it? Does it sound natural to a native English speaker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is *absolutely* **no** problem in telling that.

> I don't own myself

[Results are many including entries from some books.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20don%27t%20own%20myself%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

This simply means that you belong to someone else more than yourself. Of course, in the context of *God* it is the *truth*.

But such phrase can be used in other situations as well. Say in case of *slavery* wherein a slave has no rights on him/herself.